# Content segregation from a Text string

Tags: php, string, text-processing

I have this `"&params=&offer=art-by-jeremy-johnson"` stored in my data base.

Is there any function / method to get the output as `"Art by Jeremy Johnson"` using the above as the input value. this should be changed to the output `"Art by Jeremy Johnson"` only on the runtime.

can this be done in PHP.

Please help.

Comment: simple answer is yes. it can be done in PHP or Java. Why tag the question in Java if you only want PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
$orig = '&params=&offer=art-by-jeremy-johnson';
$parts = explode('=', $orig);
$output = explode('-', end($parts));
echo ucwords(implode(' ', $output));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, I guess you can just use `lastIndexOf` to get the last index of the equals sign, and get the remainder of the string (using `substring`).

```
if (myString.lastIndexOf("=") != -1) {
   String words = myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf("=")+1);
   words.replaceAll("-", " ");
   return words;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string="&params=&offer=art-by-jeremy-johnson";

parse_str($string,$output);
//print_r($output);
$str=ucwords(str_replace("-"," ",$output['offer']));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to not capitalized some words.

Here is a way to do it :

```
$str = "&params=&offer=art-by-jeremy-johnson";

// List of words to NOT capitalized
$keep_lower = array('by');

parse_str($str, $p);
$o = explode('-', $p['offer']);
$r = array();
foreach ($o as $w) {
    if (!in_array($w, $keep_lower))
        $w = ucfirst($w);
    $r[] = $w;
}
$offer = implode(' ', $r);
echo $offer,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
Art by Jeremy Johnson
```